# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable al ejecutar una función

Tags: python-3.x

**¿No me deja ejecutar la función alguien sabe que pasa? como puedo solucionarlo**
Es un juego de ajedrez en el que intento hacer las jugadas y sin validas del rey o no, pero me sigue tirando estos errores, alguien puede ayudarme?

```
def legal_move(before_move, last_move, move_min_max):
    jugada = [0,0] 
    while jugada == [0,0]:
        if before_move[0] - last_move[0] > move_min_max[0]:
            print("this move is not valid")
            jugada[0] = 0
        else:
            columna = before_move[0]
            jugada[0] = 1

    if before_move[1] - last_move[1] > move_min_max[1]:
        print("this move is not correct")
        jugada[1] = 0
    else:
        fila = before_move[1]
        jugada[1] = 1
    
    
    nueva_posicion = [columna, fila]

return nueva_posicion

columna = int(input("cual es la columna"))
fila = int(input("cual es la fila"))
posicion_nueva=[columna,fila]
posicion = [1,1]
legal_move(posicion_nueva,posicion, move_min_max=1)
```

> Y tengo un problema me devuelve  TypeError: 'int' object is not
> subscriptable

Comment: la variable `move_min_max` es un número, no una lista ni una tupla, por lo que no tiene indices

Comment: más allá del error que ya te lo aclararon , es común declarar las funciones con valores predeterminados para lo que se usa el = y no en la llamada a la función, o sea en este caso:  def legal_move(before_move, last_move, move_min_max=1): enotnces al llamar a la función:  def legal_move(before_move, last_move) si omito el tercer parámetro lo da como que vale 1 sino directamenete: def legal_move(before_move, last_move,2) , donde le pasamos el valor que quieras. No quiere decir que la forma que usas está mal, solo que no es convencional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El error `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` al tratar de acceder a un elemento o subindice de un objeto, pero.. que quiere decir que un objeto sea *subscriptable* o no. El termino *subscriptable* se emplea para decir que un objeto (recordemos que en python todo es un objeto) almacena a otros objetos, como lo son:

- Las cadenas `""`
- Las tuplas `()`
- Las listas `[]`
- Los diccionarios `{key:value}`

Y que a su vez se pueda acceder a sus índices usando corchetes `[]`, en el caso de los `set` no cumple tal condición, a pesar de que almacena otros objetos no se puede acceder a sus índices con `set[index]`, por tal razón, un objeto *subscriptable* es cuando contiene otros elementos y a su vez se pueda acceder a sus elementos.

El error prácticamente dice que estas tratando a un dato de tipo entero como un objeto *subscriptable* (los antes ya mencionados), lo que se podría traducir a:

```py
numero = 1
numero[0]
```

Donde se trata de acceder a la posición `0` de un número lo cual no es correcto.

Bueno y que podrías hacer en estos casos?. La respuesta es fácil, verificar tus variables ya sea las que estés enviando a una función o a las que estés tratando de acceder con la notación `object[index]`, pero si en realidad quieres tener un objeto al que puedas acceder a sus índices, puedes optar por convertir el objeto usando las distintas funciones que existen. Como:

- `str(object)`: convierte a una cadena.
- `tuple(object)`: convierte a una tupla.
- `list(object)`: convierte a una lista.
- `dict(object)`: convierte a un diccionario.

`object` es el objeto (o variable) que quieras convertir, solo recuerda almacenar el resultado en una variable, tal que `nuevo = str(viejo)` y utiliza la nueva variable en su lugar.

Otra forma puede ser con la función `range()`, solo funciona con números, la cual genera un rango de número y también puedes acceder a sus índices.

- `range(int)`: genera un rango de números desde el  0 hasta n-1

Comment: también se puede con un rango de números: numero = 1 range(numero)[0]

Comment: @tincopasan es una wiki de comunidad, puedes editarlo y añadir más información. con gusto aceptaré tu edicion

Comment: no, la respuesta es totalmente tuya, solo quice agregar una dato más a tu respuesta.

Comment: @tincopasan ya lo añadí :D, también te recomiendo leer [¿Qué es una publicación “Wiki de comunidad”?](https://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317/qu%C3%A9-es-una-publicaci%C3%B3n-wiki-de-comunidad)

Comment: La definición de suscriptable que das es imprecisa. La "subscriptabilidad" en Python es una analogía con los subíndices (de ahí su nombre) en matemáticas utilizados para referirse a un elemento en una serie (X<sub>n</sub>). Los subíndices indican el índice del elemento en la serie, tal como lo indican (casi siempre) en Python. En ese sentido, los objetos subscriptables **NO** son aquellos "objetos que contienen otros objetos" (al menos no todos ellos), sino aquellos cuyos elementos pueden ser referenciados a través de un índice. `objeto[indice]`

Comment: De hecho, una prueba de esto es que mencionas los `set`s como subscriptables, cuando no lo son, a pesar de poder "contener" otros objetos.

Comment: Cabe destacar que cuando digo "casi siempre" para referirme que los índices indican el elemento de una serie en Python, lo digo porque cualquier objeto que creemos puede ser subscriptable, siempre y cuando definamos `__getitem__`.

Comment: Por lo tanto, una definición más general sería: Un objeto subscriptable es aquel que permite el acceso a otros objetos (típicamente ítems de un *contenedor*) a través de la notación `objeto[item]`.

Comment: Fe de errata: Intenté utilizar el markdown de subíndice acá, pero no funcionó. Me refería a: Xn (X sub n)

Comment: También es confuso y conduce a malinterpretaciones decir que para solucionar este error, puedes hacer uso de "funciones" (nótese las comillas, ya que no son funciones. Son clases y se está instanciando para conseguir un *cast* de tipos). Por ejemplo, en el caso de OP que `objeto` es un entero, si hiciese `dict(objeto)`, eso no solucionaría su error. De hecho, tendría otro distinto :D

Comment: @revliscano creo que en cuanto a los objetos subcriptables usé mal la definición, y me habia olvidado que un set tampoco es subscriptable (lo siento)

Comment: @revliscano sé que en realidad de utiliza la clase del objeto para *cambiarlo* peró no quise hacerle mucha confusión al OP y entrar en detalle de clases y preferí que vea `int()`, `dict()` como una forma de covertir un tipo de dato a otro. Esta es una publicación wiki, puedes editarla y mejorar

Comment: @revliscano las publicaciones de wiki estan hechas para que todos contribuyan y se tenga una fuente confiable de información

Comment: @revliscano hice una edición verifica si esta mejor y se entiende mejor